# while(true) blocking

Tags: while-loop

I came across this code snippet online.  However, I cannot understand how the `while(true)` blocking takes place in this code:

```
private void ListenForClients()
{
  this.tcpListener.Start();

  while (true)
  {
    //blocks until a client has connected to the server
    TcpClient client = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

    //create a thread to handle communication
    //with connected client
    Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientComm));
    clientThread.Start(client);
  }
}
```

Can anyone explain it to me?  I know of using `while(true)` + breaking condition, but this thing is beyond me.

Comment: What can't you understand? Is this running on a UI thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the `while(true)` that does the blocking, it's the `AcceptTcpClient()`. This is what happens:

1. tcpListener is started.
2. The loop is started (since true is always true)
3. `this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient()` is executed and the thread stops, because [AcceptTcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclient.aspx) is a blocking method.
4. If a connection request is made the block goes away and a TcpClient is returned as the variable client.
5. A new thread is created for client
6. The loop goes back again to AcceptTcpClient and stops there until a new connection is made.

Comment: so a 'blocking method' acts like a    break; ?

Comment: No. A break takes you out of the loop, a blocking method stops the execution of the thread until the method itself releases the block. In this case the loop simply pauses until a connection is received by the listener. In this code snippet, there is no breaking out of the loop at all.

Answer (score 5):

`AcceptTcpClient` is what blocks. The `while (true)` will just endlessly loop until the process terminates, the thread is interrupted, or an exception is thrown.